# How to insert a relationship data in the bank with prism 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I'm trying to create a record in my database, I need to insert the information of a mikrotik but I have to relate the mikrotik table with a subnet table, when I create the mikrotik I need to say which subnet it belongs to, I'm using prisma 2 to make the registrations and queries in my database. my create from the prism looks like this:

```js
await prisma.mikrotik.create({
  data: {
    name: rebody.name,
    ip: rebody.ip,
    netmask: mask,
    gatway: rebody.gatway,
    password: rebody.password,
    Subrede:"I need to insert here which subnet this mikrotik belongs to"
  }
})
```

if anyone knows how I relate this record to an existing record in the subnet table, and can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added the relation of the subnet to the mikrotik, then the following code should work fine.

```
await prisma.mikrotik.create({
  data: {
    name: rebody.name,
    ip: rebody.ip,
    netmask: mask,
    gatway: rebody.gatway,
    password: rebody.password,
    Subrede: { connect: { id: 'subnet-id-it-belongs-to' } }
  }
})
```